# How to graph dates on X axis while skipping weekends d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to plot stock data with a d3 line Chart. It has ugly spaces for weekends because there is no data available for weekends. What is the best way to make the X axis chart only the dates that I have data for?

```
const x = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.datetime))
      .range([0, width]);
```

d3 newbie experiencing a heavy learning curve at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may have the same question:

```
const x = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.datetime))
      .range([0, width]);
```

Band scale graphs only the dates you have data for.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the rest of your code? I am currently having the same issue and tried using the scaleBand(), but my line is looking a little crazy. I am trying to accomplish the same exact task of plotting stock data without weekends!